# Dialogflow CX Route Groups

Tags: dialogflow-cx

I am having a bit of trouble understanding how to use route groups in Dialogflow CX: from Google's documentation I understand they were made to avoid mapping the same intent routes (if intent is X, go to flow/page Z). From their docs:

> you can define the route group once, and add a reference to the group on all relevant pages

Now, my problem is i defined route groups in the manage tab of my agent ([Dialogflow "Manage" tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCtaF.png)), but they don't seem to work nor to be selectable in each page:
[this is my "Onboarding" page for the same flow i defined routes for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aTWs.png)

Can anybody maybe help clear this up?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved the mystery, and will leave what follows for posterity:

Dialogflow is still under development, and some small things might not work as expected.

In the case of route groups, you can activate them *only* from the page view through the "+" add button.

If you click on route groups or try to modify in any other way it will only make you create a new route group.

So, once you've created a route group in the "Manage" tab, go to the page view in the visual console and click "Add route type", flag **Route Groups**  and finally add the group you've created through the + button.
[This is an example of where to add route groups](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SqmY3.png)